# Overriding @JsonProperty in a subclass with @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-serialization

I have a parent class

```
public class Parent {

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private int id;

    // getter and setter
}
```

and a corresponding subclass

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getId() { 
        return id; 
    }
}
```

While the field `id` should be serialized for `Parent` and other subclasses, I do not want to include it in the specific subclass `Child`. However, the annotation `@JsonIgnore` doesn't override the annotation `@JsonProperty` and the `id` is also included when serializing the `Child`.

Interestingly, it works with `@JsonIgnoreProperties("ID")` at class level of `Child`, but I would like to know how it can be accomplished at method level and why my approach doesn't work.

I am using Jackson in version 2.9.6.

Comment: This might help http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance    3. Ignoring Properties from a Supertype